# Should I be concerned about my egg bound betta?

Tags: fish, betta

I think my female betta is egg bound. We don't have a male, and aren't looking to breed. Do I need to be concerned or will this pass naturally? Is there anything I need to do to make sure she'll be okay and "pass" the eggs?

**Update:** There were no eggs and the fish died. I'm still not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bloat from impaction. I've heard that they can get bloated from eating pond snail eggs or other small things that aren't digestible. Another possibility is internal infection or fungus. It would help to have an image if possible.

Comment: Thanks for attempting an answer, others will come by with simular problems and will look to your answer for help.  Can you improve your answer by including references and rational for choosing between your two options?

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to worry. Although it is not natural behavior for fish to hold on to eggs forever, it will not harm them.

I have several fish that have held eggs for almost over a year now.

Sometimes it's ever better to not have a male in the tank as it can become aggressive and hurt female fish.

Comment: Fish that won't let go of eggs may well be a sign of stress, and it's not healthy for the fish. A big belly may also be a sign of various diseases or physical issues.